# Restrict the count of occurrences regex

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to find combination of dates. I am having the following regular expression.

```
\b([\d]{1,2}[\/\s-]{0,3}\d{2,4})
```

I want to match the following combinations:

```
8/1967 or 8-1967 
08/1967 same
8/67   same
08/67   same
```

I dont want it to match the following

```
08/967
```

That is i want the combination after "/" or "-" to be either 2 digit or 4 digit.
But "\d{2,4}" will give combinations if 2, 3 and 4. But I dont know how to restrict it to either 2 or 4. If there is any other problem with this regex , please let me know. help please.

Comment: there is extra `\s` that will match whitespace, for `02 2004`, is it intentional?

Comment: did you want to match `8///23` ? Post some valid and invalid examples.

Comment: your regex matches 99999, 9999, 999999 and 99 - 999, and 2 parts of  +`1-555`-`123456`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are matching months and years, do

```
\b((?:0?[1-9]|1[0-2]) ?[/-] ?(?:[12][0-9])?[0-9]{2})\b
```

Explanation:

- `\b` - a word boundary between non-alphanumeric and alphanumeric character
- `(?:0?[1-9]|1[0-2])` - 1-12 and 01-12 (with leading zero)
- `?` - possible space on either side of the separator
- `[-/]` 1 separator character, either - or /
- `(?:[12][0-9])?[0-9]{2})` - either 4-digit number that starts with 1 or 2, or 2 digit number with any digits.
- `\b` - ends with word boundary (the next character is not alphanumeric).

This will match the following strings: `03-1902`, `12 / 2014`, `6 / 03`

but will not match any of `3 / 3009`, `13/2009`, or `26-30`, or `3///60`, or `12/34567`.

I use `[0-9]` instead of `\d` because `\d` is locale dependent.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/yO4pV1/2)

---

To match a date range (are you possibly doing a cv/resume parser here?), you can do:

```
date_re = r'\b((?:0?[1-9]|1[0-2]) ?[/-] ?(?:[12][0-9])?[0-9]{2})\b'
date_span = r'%s(?:[\s-]+)-\s*%s' % (date_re, date_re)
```

which produces the following regular expression in `date_span`:

```
\b((?:0?[1-9]|1[0-2]) ?[/-] ?(?:[12][0-9])?[0-9]{2})\b(?:[\s-]+)-\s*\b((?:0?[1-9]|1[0-2]) ?[/-] ?(?:[12][0-9])?[0-9]{2})\b
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/nN3lQ2/1)

Comment: @Antii Haapala - Yeah. actually , it was a part of the whole match I was trying to do. I will edit the question with more details. Your answer for the context is right. But I need a more complex one. I will put here.

Comment: Please don't, all answers here are to the 1 question, I don't like shooting to a moving target.

Comment: Okay. I will post a new question then.

Comment: Yeah a kind of resume parsing. its hard when we dig into the core. I will read your regex. I need some time to understand it.

Comment: This was good. But anyway to avoid the matching pattern here. https://regex101.com/r/nN3lQ2/2

Answer (score 2):

Change `\d{2,4}` into `\d{2}(\d{2})?`

This will get you what you want.

First match 2 digits, then a two digits combination for only one time or not.

That's exactly 2 or 4 digits.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Thanks! My answer is updated. There's something you might need to correct in your answer.`(?:0?\d|1[0-2])` this part will match 00 or a single 0, maybe `(?:[1-9]|0[1-9]|1[0-2])` is better.(i cannot comment on others' answer...)

Answer (score 0):

```
\b((?<!\/)[\d]{1,2}[\/\s-]{0,3}(?!\d{3}\b)\d{2,4})
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/wX9fR1/11

`(?!\d{3}\b` will make 3 digits wont be matched.